# Prevent special characters and accents (´`¨^~) in input (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field restricted to 3 characters where I only want to allow numbers

I have a solution that almost works for every case: (problem below)

```js
// Avoid any unwanted keys from showing
$("input#test").keypress(function(event) {
  if (!isApprovedKeyCode(event)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});

// Useless try to prevent accents from showing
$("input#test").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 229) { // ´
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});

//A few character modifiers (i.e. ´`¨^~) do not trigger keypress
//This ensures the input only contains numbers
$("input#test").keyup(function(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var validString = element.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  if (validString !== element.value) {
    element.value = validString;
  }
});

function isApprovedKeyCode(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
  var character = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
  return isValidDigit(character);
}

function isValidDigit(character) {
  var result = /\d/.test(character);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="test" />
```

The problems:

- Accents are still shown (until the keyup removes them from the input)
- If you have a 2 digit value and you input an accent (´`¨^~) (which disappears) and then try to type a number, the number is never shown due to the 3 character restriction. Example:

  - Set the input to 12
  - Press ´ key
  - Press 3
  - In this case the 3 will not appear in the input, and you will need press it again

As you can see I have tried to prevent this in the keydown, but none of the event prevention tried seems to work with these keys

I have also tried using an input with type="number". Quick example:

```js
// Limit lenght
$("input#test").keydown(function(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  if(element.value.length > 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" id="test" />
```

This also shows accents and allows to add more than the limit by pressing an accent followed by numbers

Any idea on a proper solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Kind of tricky for me to try to answer directly (can only get to accents through alt codes), but have you considered adding a filter on the keydown that *only* lets keycodes associated with number keys through?

Comment: Yes, that was our initial implementation. It doesn't solve the problem plus it will block French keyboard where you need to press Shift in order to type the "regular" numbers.
As you can see in the example I tried to block the accent on keydown with event.preventDefault, event.stopImmediatePropagation and event.stopPropagation, but it seems that none of those block the accents from showing and affecting the following key. I am testing it with Spanish and French keyboards that have accents in the keyboard

Comment: My other other suggestion is for the 2-digit issue to limit the input length programmatically (via jquery) rather than setting it via attribute. Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't think about that, and I managed to make it work limiting the length in jQuery (similar to the example for type="number"). Unfortunately I discovered that String.fromCharCode() doesn't work with the keypad on Firefox, so I am reverting to our previous implementation where we just do the keyup cleaning, since the impact is minimum (typing a non-numeric key followed by a numeric key on the 3rd digit)

Comment: both examples seem to be working. Can you clarify the problem?